# How to find digits in string

Tags: python

```
text1 = 'three digits NUMBER_001'
```

The code below properly finds three digits in a string following after the characters "NUMBER_": `['NUMBER_123']`:

```
result = re.findall('NUMBER_\d\d\d', text1)
print result
```

But it returns incomplete number if the number is made of more than three digits:

```
text2 = 'four digits number is NUMBER_0001'
result = re.findall('NUMBER_\d\d\d', text2)
```

Is there a way to find all the continuous digits placed after the characters "NUMBER_"?

Comment: `NUMBER_\d+`? I'd recommend an introductory regex tutorial.

Comment: So what? Why make your deadlines and/or poor time management our problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `()` in your regEx:

```
result = re.findall('NUMBER_(\d\d\d)', text1)
```

the same shall be written as,

```
result = re.findall('NUMBER_(\d{3})', text1)
```

Alternatively, any number of digits:

```
result = re.findall('NUMBER_([\d]+)', text1)
```

OR

```
result = re.findall('NUMBER_([0-9]+)', text1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate a quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your regexp by:

```
result = re.findall('NUMBER_([0-9]+)', text1)
```

Comment: That or you may use `(\d+)` instead of `([0-9]+)`.